# Increment Integer with leading zero

Tags: date, vbscript, asp-classic

How do I increment an integer without losing the leading zero?

here is my code.

```
for i = week1From to week1To
    dayWeek1(ctr)=i
    ctr=ctr+1
next
```

If my variables are this.

```
week1From = 03
week1To = 07
```

the result would

```
dayWeek1(1) = 3
dayWeek1(2) = 4
dayWeek1(3) = 5
dayweek1(4) = 6
dayWeek1(5) = 7
```

how can i make it like this?

```
dayWeek1(1) = 03
dayWeek1(2) = 04
dayWeek1(3) = 05
dayweek1(4) = 06
dayWeek1(5) = 07
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, there is no leading 0. 3 is 3 and 4 is 4. The leading 0 is only necessary when you're viewing the value or using it in some other context where the leading 0 is required. So just add it when you output the value, like:

```vb
Response.Write "0" & dayWeek1(i) & vbCrLf
```

Here's a little trick if you have values from 0-99 and you want the 1-digit values (0-9) to have a leading 0:

```vb
Response.Write Right("0" & value, 2)
```

This will output the right-most 2 digits, so 1 becomes "01" and 99 becomes "099" but only the right-most 2 digits are printed, so "99".